# Why scss is not blowing up for wrong css value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

I am using scss with haml in my rails3 project. I mistakenly typed

```
zindex: 99999
```

instead of

```
z-index: 9999
```

SCSS did not blow up.

I thought one of the benefits of using haml/sass/scss was not invalid css values are not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sass / SCSS don't enforce valid CSS properties, just valid syntax. Your `zindex: 9999` is still a valid syntax, but not a recognized CSS property.

CSS itself allows things such as custom browser extensions such as `-moz-whatever` that other browsers don't recognize. It would be too restrictive and impossible to maintain a list of up-to-date properties for Sass to filter.